# Does an Oedipus the King manga actually exist?

Tags: zankyou-no-terror

In episode 2 of *Terror in Resonance*, Lisa is shown reading a manga that depicts the events of *Oedipus the King*. Does such a manga actually exist?

A preliminary search in English didn't give anything useful, and it's pretty likely that this manga might have been invented for the sake of the anime, tying into the other allusions to the work (which seem to be relevant to the plot, but since I'm only on the second episode, I can't tell yet).

But since I enjoyed the play, I'd like to ask just in case there *is* such a manga, and if my searches just didn't work out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if you're asking this question without the knowledge that Oedipus is originally  from a Greek mythology or not. He is a tragic hero and a king in Thebes and his name translates to the Ancient Greek "Swollen Foot". Here's the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus) for that.

To answer your question: No, I don't think a manga version of Oedipus the King exists. Although there may be an English comic about it somewhere. The reference in Zankyou no Terror was most likely for plot rather than an actual cameo.

As a disclaimer, I haven't finished it either and stopped at episode 9 or 10. Also, this is my first shot an answering a question here @stack-sites, I hope I did good :)

Comment: You did just fine, welcome aboard :)

Comment: Yep, the reason I was interested in whether such a manga exists is because I read Sophocles' dramatisation of the myth and rather liked it. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Accepting this answer since while it seems true that _some_ adaptation exists, I was mostly interested in whether the manga shown in-universe does too.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's the same manga you mean, but there is a manga about the story of King Oedipus. [Manga of the Greek Myths: Volume 4, Tragic King Oedipus](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4122043344), by Machiko Satonaka, released 25th February 2004 by Chuokoron-Shinsha, Inc.

[image: Cover]